# Increase typing speed on automatically typing javascript code

Tags: javascript, html, css

I currently have a Javascript code that allows text to be automatically typed to the screen. However, I can't figure out how to make the typing speed faster. Right now, it is taking too long for the whole code to be displayed. I'm trying to get the "typerwriter" effect to display faster.

```js
 function setupTypewriter(t) {
        var HTML = t.innerHTML;

        t.innerHTML = "";

        var cursorPosition = 0,
            tag = "",
            writingTag = false,
            tagOpen = false,
            typeSpeed = 100,
        tempTypeSpeed = 0;

        var type = function() {
        
            if (writingTag === true) {
                tag += HTML[cursorPosition];
            }

            if (HTML[cursorPosition] === "<") {
                tempTypeSpeed = 0;
                if (tagOpen) {
                    tagOpen = false;
                    writingTag = true;
                } else {
                    tag = "";
                    tagOpen = true;
                    writingTag = true;
                    tag += HTML[cursorPosition];
                }
            }
            if (!writingTag && tagOpen) {
                tag.innerHTML += HTML[cursorPosition];
            }
            if (!writingTag && !tagOpen) {
                if (HTML[cursorPosition] === " ") {
                    tempTypeSpeed = 30;
                }
                else {
                    tempTypeSpeed = (Math.random() * typeSpeed) + 100;
                }
                t.innerHTML += HTML[cursorPosition];
            }
            if (writingTag === true && HTML[cursorPosition] === ">") {
                tempTypeSpeed = (Math.random() * typeSpeed) + 100;
                writingTag = false;
                if (tagOpen) {
                    var newSpan = document.createElement("span");
                    t.appendChild(newSpan);
                    newSpan.innerHTML = tag;
                    tag = newSpan.firstChild;
                }
            }

            cursorPosition += 1;
            if (cursorPosition < HTML.length - 1) {
                setTimeout(type, tempTypeSpeed);
            }

        };

        return {
            type: type
        };
    }

    var typer = document.getElementById('typewriter');

    typewriter = setupTypewriter(typewriter);

    typewriter.type();
```

```css
#top{
  height: calc(100vh);
  padding: 4em;
  color: rgba(255,255,255,.75);
}

.var-highlight {
    color: #4d9cd6;
  }
  
  .string-highlight {
    color: rgba(253, 149, 90, 0.8);
  }
  .object {
      color: #9cdcfe;
  }
  .equal {
      color: #ffffff;
  }
  .paranthesis {
      color: #f1d700;
  }
  .objectProp {
      color: #9cdcfe;
  }
  .array {
      color: #da70d6;
  }
  pre {
      color: #ffffff;
  }
  #typewriter {
    font-size: 2em;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: "Courier New";
    margin-top: 6%;
    margin-left: 4%;
  }
  #typewriter:after {
    content: "|";
    -webkit-animation: blink 500ms linear infinite alternate;
            animation: blink 500ms linear infinite alternate;
  }
  .fa-chevron-down {
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    margin-bottom: 1%;
  }
  
  @-webkit-keyframes blink {
    0% {
      opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }
  @keyframes blink {
    0% {
      opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid" id="top">
    <pre id="typewriter">
        <span class="var-highlight">var</span> <span class="object">object</span><span class="equal"> =</span> <span class="paranthesis">{</span>
           <span class="objectProp"> name:</span> <span class="string-highlight">'Alyssa Durante'</span>,
           <span class="objectProp"> occupation:</span>  <span class="string-highlight">'UI Engineer'</span>,
           <span class="objectProp"> location:</span> <span class="string-highlight">'NYC'</span>,
           <span class="objectProp"> specialties:</span> <span class="array">[</span><span class="string-highlight">'Modern interfaces'</span>,
                        <span class="string-highlight">'Clean code'</span>,
                        <span class="string-highlight">'Being awesome'</span><span class="array">]</span>;
        <span class="paranthesis">}</span>; </pre>
        </div>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried adjusting the typeSpeed property?

Comment: yes, but it doesn't seem to be doing much

Comment: Oh, i figured it out. It had to do with the integer at the end of the tempTypeSpeed equation!

Comment: You can either answer your own question or delete the question.

Answer (score 0):

Your `setupTypewriter()` function has some initial configuration variables defined at the top. Looking at the function, it appears that increasing `typeSpeed` from `100` should increase the typing speed.

Answer (score 0):

I would change the typeSpeed property and then use it instead of the constant 100 value that you have in 2 places. The smaller that typeSpeed number the faster you'll type. Also calculate the typespeed for the space char based on it. I've modified your snippet below.

```js
function setupTypewriter(t) {
        var HTML = t.innerHTML;

        t.innerHTML = "";

        var cursorPosition = 0,
            tag = "",
            writingTag = false,
            tagOpen = false,
            typeSpeed = 50,
        tempTypeSpeed = 0;

        var type = function() {
        
            if (writingTag === true) {
                tag += HTML[cursorPosition];
            }

            if (HTML[cursorPosition] === "<") {
                tempTypeSpeed = 0;
                if (tagOpen) {
                    tagOpen = false;
                    writingTag = true;
                } else {
                    tag = "";
                    tagOpen = true;
                    writingTag = true;
                    tag += HTML[cursorPosition];
                }
            }
            if (!writingTag && tagOpen) {
                tag.innerHTML += HTML[cursorPosition];
            }
            if (!writingTag && !tagOpen) {
                if (HTML[cursorPosition] === " ") {
                    tempTypeSpeed = typeSpeed/3;
                }
                else {
                    tempTypeSpeed = (Math.random() * typeSpeed) + typeSpeed;
                }
                t.innerHTML += HTML[cursorPosition];
            }
            if (writingTag === true && HTML[cursorPosition] === ">") {
                tempTypeSpeed = (Math.random() * typeSpeed) + typeSpeed;
                writingTag = false;
                if (tagOpen) {
                    var newSpan = document.createElement("span");
                    t.appendChild(newSpan);
                    newSpan.innerHTML = tag;
                    tag = newSpan.firstChild;
                }
            }

            cursorPosition += 1;
            if (cursorPosition < HTML.length - 1) {
                setTimeout(type, tempTypeSpeed);
            }

        };

        return {
            type: type
        };
    }

    var typer = document.getElementById('typewriter');

    typewriter = setupTypewriter(typewriter);

    typewriter.type();
```

```css
#top{
  height: calc(100vh);
  padding: 4em;
  color: rgba(255,255,255,.75);
}

.var-highlight {
    color: #4d9cd6;
  }
  
  .string-highlight {
    color: rgba(253, 149, 90, 0.8);
  }
  .object {
      color: #9cdcfe;
  }
  .equal {
      color: #ffffff;
  }
  .paranthesis {
      color: #f1d700;
  }
  .objectProp {
      color: #9cdcfe;
  }
  .array {
      color: #da70d6;
  }
  pre {
      color: #ffffff;
  }
  #typewriter {
    font-size: 2em;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: "Courier New";
    margin-top: 6%;
    margin-left: 4%;
  }
  #typewriter:after {
    content: "|";
    -webkit-animation: blink 500ms linear infinite alternate;
            animation: blink 500ms linear infinite alternate;
  }
  .fa-chevron-down {
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    margin-bottom: 1%;
  }
  
  @-webkit-keyframes blink {
    0% {
      opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }
  @keyframes blink {
    0% {
      opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid" id="top">
    <pre id="typewriter">
        <span class="var-highlight">var</span> <span class="object">object</span><span class="equal"> =</span> <span class="paranthesis">{</span>
           <span class="objectProp"> name:</span> <span class="string-highlight">'Alyssa Durante'</span>,
           <span class="objectProp"> occupation:</span>  <span class="string-highlight">'UI Engineer'</span>,
           <span class="objectProp"> location:</span> <span class="string-highlight">'NYC'</span>,
           <span class="objectProp"> specialties:</span> <span class="array">[</span><span class="string-highlight">'Modern interfaces'</span>,
                        <span class="string-highlight">'Clean code'</span>,
                        <span class="string-highlight">'Being awesome'</span><span class="array">]</span>;
        <span class="paranthesis">}</span>; </pre>
        </div>
```